# Unpaired Wilcox test for the whole column

Tags: sapply

this is my document and I am new to R
I need to do a wilcoxon test to compare NCs vs RCs (patients that responded or not to the treatment) for each column after the Response column. I know how to do it manually for a given column, but I don't know how to make it a loop thing since 8 will have many columns to test.

I have no idea how to do it. I have been trying with anything I find on the internet, but wi no success

[this is my excell file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg5gw.png)

```
All<-All frequencies.xls

All
 sapply(2:ncol(All), 
    function(x) {
  wilcox.test(All[All$Response == "NC", x],
          All[All$Response == "RC", x], exact=FALSE)$p.val 
 }
 )
```

thanks for any input